# XSLT recursive html clean up

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm working with a xslt to cleanup a html code that is generated by an editor.

The code contains the following structure:

```
<span name="x">1<b>test text</b>
    <span name="y">2</span>
</span>
<span name="y">3
    <span name="y">4</span>
    <span name="x">1</span>
</span>
<span name="y">5<i>test</i>
    <span name="y"><u>6</u>7</span>
</span>
```

The thing is that xslt needs to preserve the HTML structure. And needs to complete 2 actions. 
if it finds a span with the name x. It needs to remove it. (This is not an problem)

But when it finds a y that's not inside a x. It needs to take the child nodes (value of `node()`), and  place them in the output. The child nodes need to be checked for any other spans.

A.t.m i did have some xslt's that find the first level spans (number 1 and 3). But it copies the inner html, and doesn't apply the templates for the innerHTML.

Did anyone have this problem, or know a solution?

EDIT: Needed output as explained above.

```
345<i>test</i><u>6</u>7
```

EDIT2: XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="span[@name='x']">
 //This deletes the node.. But only one level?
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template  match="span[@name='y']">
 //This needs to play all templates again to remove or get inner nodes() see case x & y
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Pls. share your generated XSLT and required output.

Comment: See the edits in my post

Comment: It works fine for me, if you add <xsl:apply-templates/> in <xsl:template  match="span[@name='y']"> template

Comment: I does indeed. but i don't understand why. I was trying to make copies of the node() value. Why only need to use apply-templates?

Comment: This works because of the ["Identity transform"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template which is already part of your stylesheet.

Comment: @NavinRawat: please make your comment into an answer so this question doesn't need to stay in the "unanswered" status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to include apply-templates in your last template to get desired output.